# Noncopyable and Nonmovable together?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a base class both noncopyable and nonmovable.

```
class noncopyable {
protected:
  noncopyable() = default;
  ~noncopyable() = default;

  noncopyable(noncopyable const &) = delete;
  noncopyable &operator=(noncopyable const &) = delete;
};

class nonmovable {
protected:
  nonmovable() = default;
  ~nonmovable() = default;

  nonmovable(nonmovable &&) = delete;
  nonmovable &operator=(nonmovable &&) = delete;
};
```

Is there any scenario that a class should be both noncopyable and nonmovable?

```
class non : public noncopyable, public nonmovable {
};

class foo : public non {
};
```

If there, what should be the convenient name for the "non" class here?

Comment: "is that convenient?" not really.

Comment: Sure, it can be quite useful. But you can also use `boost::noncopyable`. And usually you don't need public inheritance. And the deleted stuff can be `private`.

Comment: Your `nonmovable` is exactly the same as your `noncopyable`. What is it supposed to actually look like?

Comment: What do you define as "convenient"?     For a class that should not be copied or moved, your approach may be useful.   Also, do you intend that your `noncopyable` and `nonmoveable` are essentially the same, or is that a typo?

Comment: You are not overriding the `&&` move semantics; therefore you're not making the class nonmovable. I think you should revise your question so that it is more clear what you mean. I think you're referring to `non-assignable` rather than `non-movable`.

Comment: I find that abusing inheritance for this is actually more complicated then just deleting the appropriate member functions. You need to be aware of the rule of 5/0 anyways.

Comment: I have corrected the question. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a "noncopyable" will work, an "nonmovable" base class will not provide what you expect:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct nonmovable
{
    nonmovable() = default;
    nonmovable(const nonmovable&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    nonmovable& operator = (const nonmovable&) { std::cout << "asign\n"; return *this; }
    nonmovable(nonmovable&&) = delete;
    nonmovable& operator = (nonmovable&&)  = delete;
};

struct X : nonmovable {};

int main()
{
    nonmovable n0;
    nonmovable n1(n0);
    // error: use of deleted function ‘nonmovable::nonmovable(nonmovable&&)’:
    //nonmovable n2(std::move(n0));

    X x0;
    X x1(x0);
    // However, X has a copy constructor not applying a move.
    X x2(std::move(x0));
}
```

In addition, move construction and move assignment must be enabled explicitly after deletion of the copy constructor, if desiered:

```
struct noncopyable
{
    noncopyable() = default;
    // Deletion of copy constructor and copy assignment makes the class
    // non-movable, too.
    noncopyable(const noncopyable&) = delete;
    noncopyable& operator = (const noncopyable&) = delete;

    // Move construction and move assignment must be enabled explicitly, if desiered.
    noncopyable(noncopyable&&) = default;
    noncopyable& operator = (noncopyable&&)  = default;
};
```

The, names "noncopyable" and "nonmovable" itself are good descriptive names. However, "boost::noncopyable" is both (non copyable and non movable), which might be a better (historical) design decision.

Comment: does "X x2(std::move(x0));" call move constructor or copy constructer. If the copy constructor is called. I reached my aim.

Comment: @mustafagonul the copy constructor of X (X has no move constructor, whatsoever)

Answer (score 6):

It has been argued, for instance [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310118/object-lifetime-invariants-vs-move-semantics), that `nonmoveable` as demonstrated is a bad idea in the first place.

There are four reasonable options:

1. Type is naturally copyable and moveable.
2. Type is non-copyable, but moveable.
   This happens often if it is managing a resource, and copying the resource is impossible, or so expensive as to be undesirable.
3. Type has no special moveability -- move ctor simply calls copy ctor.
   This mostly happens if for technical reasons, you don't want to create an "empty state" for objects of this type, or there is no cheap / natural way to leave the moved-from object in any acceptable state.
4. Type is neither copyable nor moveable.
   This may happen with a static singleton or something like this, where moving or copying it is something that should never happen in your program and you want to prevent from happening with a compile-time error.

If the type is copyable, but moving it fails, this is strictly a bad arrangement, and instead move should be made to fallback to copy. There's no advantage to making a move fail when a copy would be okay, it only inhibits generic programming.

So maybe you should only have "noncopyable" and "non", but not "nonmoveable" ?

Answer (score -3):

as an example - signleton pattern. Also, if u defined copy-constructor/assignment operator/destructor, move-constructor/assignment wont be generated.

Comment: not really. take a look at the mutex class in standard C++

Comment: And? mutex is movable by standard. It's up to vendor, how to implement it.

Comment: @jonezq [This disagrees](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/mutex/). A `std::mutex` is not movable by the standard.

Comment: supposed to write not movable, yes. I meant, standard says nothing about design patterns. As an example msvc2012: _Mutex_base (base class for all mutex types) - isn't a singleton.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Does "singleton pattern" mean that the proposed classes `noncopyable` and `nonmovable` are correct and convenient or not? Nothing you wrote seems to be related to that, which makes "this not an answer".

Comment: well it will work, so it's correct, especially for Indian coders(which getting paid for each coding line)

Comment: The point is that non -movable/non-copiable is not the same as singletone. sometimes you want many instances of the same class but without the ability to move them, like mutexes. this is not singletone where you want just one instance